# Pixel size difference

Tags: html

Why any differents between Chrome and screen capture ?

I'm using bootstrap. I would like to have 50px of true pixels.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> 
    <div class="modal-content"> 
        <div class="modal-header"> </div> 
        <div class="modal-body"> </div> 
        <div class="modal-footer"> </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .modal-header{ 
       height: 50px; 
 }
```

[image]

Comment: if you post the code we could be able to tell for sure, but i am thinking its using % instead of pixels or is inheriting atttributes. Also dimensions are calculated using a variety of factors Border, padding , width all effect the final render size.

Comment: I only want to define in pixel to have the same design between web application and desktop application. I added css height size to 50px

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: `code`
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
`code`

`code`
.modal-header{
 height: 50px;
}
`code`

Comment: If you look at [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) I have the same problem on all controls

Comment: adjust your padding or add the amount of padding to your height.

Comment: @ZeBobo5, your comments materially change the question, adding new info, etc.  Please edit to incorporate.

Answer (score 0):

in my sample using your code I have exactly 50 height on the header so I am not sure what you are seeing.
[image: Screenshot]

Which browser are you having issue with?

```css
.modal-header{ 
       height: 50px; 
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> 
    <div class="modal-content"> 
        <div class="modal-header">Modal Header </div> 
        <div class="modal-body">Modal Body</div> 
        <div class="modal-footer"> The footer is here</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```